# Laravel 5 with Guzzle and NodeJS

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, reactjs, laravel-5

I have a Node server:

```
'use strict';

require('babel-register')({
    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
});
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOMServer = require('react-dom/server');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/', function(req, res) {
    try {
        var view = path.resolve('public/src/' + req.query.module);
        var component = require(view).default;
        var props = req.body || null;
        res.status(200).send(
            ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
                React.createElement(component, props)
            )
        );
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err.message);
    }
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Listening carefully...')
```

And a Laravel route:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

Route::get('/{name?}', function($name)  {
    $client = new Client(['base_url' => 'http://10.0.1.123:3000']);
    $response = $client->post('/', [
        'json' => ['name' => ucfirst($name ?: 'World')],
        'query' => ['module' => 'hello'],
    ]);
    $contents = $response->getBody()->getContents();

    return response($contents, 200);
});
```

The problem is when I browse to the page it gives me:

> Error creating resource: [message] fopen(/?module=hello): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

I think I need that to read as just `hello`, without all the query syntax with it, because my Laravel route is `/hello`, and not `?module=hello`

How can I get this to do that?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that base_url should be base_uri, must have been a typo from the tutorial I used or the docs :/